# Is it possible to store Map<String,Object> in sharedPeference without converting to json?

Tags: android

I am trying to store a hash map in shared preference which contains the key as a string and value an object. The json conversion of my class is

```
{"avlStatus":1,"isOnline":false}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are welcome to convert it to XML instead of JSON. Or some other string notation. However, you cannot store arbitrary data structures in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Is there any way by using android Parcelable

Comment: @leo: No. First, `Parcelable` is *never* suitable for durable storage. Second, `SharedPreferences` cannot hold a `Parcelable` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences probably isn't the best solution if you want to store a structure. However you could always write private data to internal storage. [Google's Data Storage doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) shows the following implementation of writing private data to internal storage:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

To retrieve your file simply call `openFileInput()` and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
Read bytes from the file with read().
Then close the stream with close().

Comment: From there you could serialize whatever JSON you've stored.